# How could it be possible if we have (a,b) then it is an open interval?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am really wondered why do we consider these kind of intervals open, how come they are not considered closed? is there any mathematical proof or i just have to accept the way it is (as i did in high-school!).

Comment: It's just a definition. Definitions don't require proof.The concept of _closed_ is that a set of real numbers is closed if you can't get out of the set by taking the limit of a sequence of elements from the set. Thus, a bounded interval is closed if and only if it can be expressed as $[a,b]$.

Comment: It's "open" because it's not "closed", like $[a, b]$. What makes $[a, b]$ closed? Well, it's not "open"...

Comment: I think that, ultimately, all the other definitions for "open" are either informed by the definition for "open" in $\mathbb{R}$ (metric-space open, topologically open). Since the root of all them is named rather arbitrarily, all of its children are similarly arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in fact a definition of what it means for sets to be open or closed, though it usually comes up in topology (so is maybe a little past what you would cover in a precalculus class).

The definition is based on the *boundary points* of a set.  A set is called *open* if it doesn't contain any of its boundary points. So for an interval $(a,b)$, the boundary points of this interval are $a$ and $b$, neither of which is included in the set. So this interval is called open. A set is *closed* if **all** of the boundary points are in the set.  So the interval $[a,b]$ would be closed, and $[a,b)$ would be neither open nor closed (since it contains some but not all of the boundary points).

Comment: i got what u said so other question came and that is how should i check if a number like x belongs to an interval like (a,b) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as @quasi mentions, it's a definition. `(a,b)` refers to an interval that doesn't include its endpoints, so is considered open. `[a,b]` refers to an interval that does include its endpoints, so is considered closed.